# OpenCover coverage stats with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, iis, opencover

I've been trying to get some coverage stats with OpenCover for my Selenium Webdriver automated tests to get a better idea what areas my tests aren't covering on the app.

I've currently set up the web app on my local IIS and I'm using SpecFlow to do the automation.

Using OpenCover.Console.exe I'm am currently using this line to attempt to get some coverage.

OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe" -targetargs:-debug -targetdir:"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AmberUI\deploy\bin" -register:user

I am getting a results.xml file but it's spitting out a load of gibberish

```
<Method visited="true" cyclomaticComplexity="1" nPathComplexity="0" sequenceCoverage="0" branchCoverage="0" isConstructor="false" isStatic="false" isGetter="false" isSetter="false">
          <Summary numSequencePoints="0" visitedSequencePoints="0" numBranchPoints="0" visitedBranchPoints="0" sequenceCoverage="0" branchCoverage="0" maxCyclomaticComplexity="1" minCyclomaticComplexity="1" visitedClasses="0" numClasses="0" visitedMethods="0" numMethods="0" />
          <MetadataToken>100663387</MetadataToken>
          <Name>System.Int32 &lt;&gt;f__AnonymousType9`2::GetHashCode()</Name>
          <SequencePoints />
          <BranchPoints />
          <MethodPoint vc="4" uspid="300197" ordinal="0" offset="0" />
        </Method>
```

Has anyone been able to successfully get coverage stats with Selenium Webdriver with OpenCover?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCover documentation recommends that you use a tool called ReportGenerator to turn the gibberish into a pretty report.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to get what I want after digging through google. The results show parts of the app which my automated tests are hitting.

I have one further question, since I'm attaching the process to w3wp.exe I want to then shutdown OpenCover afterwards. Is there a command to shutdown?

Comment: @MattC shut down the process being covered